# Timer thread for backing up

Tags: c#, vb.net, timer, countdowntimer

If I want to save something into my database on interval of 5 min., and I have decided to use a separate thread for that (if there's a better way - enlighten me), then what will be better:

- just create the thread and hold it on sleep for 5 min, then make it call the Save function, and then sleep again. OR
- make use of the Timer class (I haven't examined it much) and make somewhat of a countdown with it, if that's possible, whereas on end of the time - call the Save function - and then start the countdown again. OR
- some other way

P.S. You can give code examples if you feel like it.

Comment: Second way sounds good... You rarely ever put a thread to sleep intentionally, and especially not 5 mins...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `System.Threading.Timer`.

Add to your class a field of type `System.Threading.Timer`:

```
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
```

Then initialise it in your class's constructor:

```
_timer = new Timer
(
    onSave, 
    null,  // State; not used.
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
);
```

Then add an `onSave()` and put your save logic into it:

```
private void onSave(object state)
{
    // Handle your save here.
}
```

You don't want to burn an entire thread just for a callback every five minutes.

The other advantage to using a timer is it makes it much easier to cancel it when the program wants to shut down (or for any other reason). If you have a thread sitting in a Sleep() then it's not easy to cancel the Sleep()!

To stop the timer from running, you just do this:

```
_timer.Change(-1, -1);
```

To start it going again:

```
_timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Check [the documentation for `System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Timer.aspx) for more details.

One thing to watch out for is if the call to `onSave()` takes longer than the timer period. In that case, you might want to disable the timer at the beginning of `onSave()` (by calling `_timer.Change(-1, -1);`) and re-enable the timer at the end.

Comment: I am trying to make the thing with the Timer that you suggested but I am getting *'null' is not declared. 'null' constant is no longer supported* compile time error. And I can't really find a working solution for that.

Comment: @Syspect If you use vb.net its `Nothing` instead of `null`

Comment: @RaphaelSmit - yep, thanks. But now I am getting *Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.* for the following line of code: `_timer = New Timer(onSave(), Nothing, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))'. And I looked in the documentation for `Timer` class and it has exactly the constructor I am using... It seems like I am not using the correct `Timer` class, although I even try by writing the full importing path.

Comment: @Syspect Have you tried using the full namespace? `Dim _timer = New System.Threading.Timer(onSave(), Nothing, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))`

Comment: @Syspect If you are using VB, why did you tag your question as C#? My answer pertains only to C#... I don't know how to fix it for VB.

Comment: @RaphaelSmit - yes, I have tried using the full namespace, as I said in my previous comment. I still get the same error.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - because VB and C# basically use the same API and it doesn't matter for me whether the answer is in C# or VB - I can rewrite it.

Comment: @Syspect In C# you must not put the parenthesis on the end of the  `onSave` passed to the Timer constructor, otherwise you will be calling a method and not passing a method. Looking at the VB sample code on MSDN, it seems quite different for VB involving some AddressOf thing.